# How can I wrap spark-dataframe to root element?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a simple json array, and I am able to read it in spark- dataframe.
Can you help to wrap that columns in to custom-root tag. 
to be more precise, exactly opposite to explode option, confining whole dataframe rows of custom target root-column.

```
Initial Json Data:
[{"tpeKeyId":"301461865","acctImplMgrId":null,"acctMgrId":null,"agreCancDt":null,"agreEffDt":null,"pltfrmNm":"EMPLOYEE NAVIGATOR","premPyRmtInd":null,"recCrtTs":"2016-11-08 13:01:44.290418","recCrtUsrId":"testedname","recUpdtTs":"2018-10-16 12:16:21.579446","recUpdtUsrId":"testname","spclInstrFormCd":null,"sysCd":null,"tpeNm":"EMPLOYEE NAVIGATOR","univPrdcrId":"9393939393"},{"tpeKeyId":"901972280","acctImplMgrId":null,"acctMgrId":null,"agreCancDt":null,"agreEffDt":null,"pltfrmNm":"datalion","premPyRmtInd":null,"recCrtTs":"2018-12-10 01:36:14.925833","recCrtUsrId":"exactlydata","recUpdtTs":"2018-12-10 01:36:14.925833","recUpdtUsrId":"datalion        ","spclInstrFormCd":null,"sysCd":null,"tpeNm":"lialion","univPrdcrId":"89899898989"}]

First Dataframe:

+-------------+---------+----------+---------+------------------+------------+--------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+----------------+---------------+-----+---------+------------------+-----------+
|acctImplMgrId|acctMgrId|agreCancDt|agreEffDt|pltfrmNm          |premPyRmtInd|recCrtTs                  |recCrtUsrId|recUpdtTs                 |recUpdtUsrId    |spclInstrFormCd|sysCd|tpeKeyId |tpeNm             |univPrdcrId|
+-------------+---------+----------+---------+------------------+------------+--------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+----------------+---------------+-----+---------+------------------+-----------+
|null         |null     |null      |null     |EMPLOYEE NAVIGATOR|null        |2016-11-08 13:01:44.290418|testedname |2018-10-16 12:16:21.579446|testname        |null           |null |301461865|EMPLOYEE NAVIGATOR|9393939393 |
|null         |null     |null      |null     |datalion          |null        |2018-12-10 01:36:14.925833|exactlydata|2018-12-10 01:36:14.925833|datalion        |null           |null |901972280|lialion           |89899898989|
+-------------+---------+----------+---------+------------------+------------+--------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+----------------+---------------+-----+---------+------------------+-----------+
```

After concatenating root tag manually:

```scala
    val addingRootTag= "{ \"roottag\" :" + fileContents + "}"    
    val rootTagDf = spark.read.json(Seq(addingRootTag).toDS())
    rootTagDf.show(false)
Second Dataframe:
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|roottag                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[,,,, EMPLOYEE NAVIGATOR,, 2016-11-08 13:01:44.290418, testedname, 2018-10-16 12:16:21.579446, testname,,, 301461865, EMPLOYEE NAVIGATOR, 9393939393], [,,,, datalion,, 2018-12-10 01:36:14.925833, exactlydata, 2018-12-10 01:36:14.925833, datalion        ,,, 901972280, lialion, 89899898989]]|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Question is, Do we have any such method in spark-framework supported api to avoid manual concatenation of the `roottag` and getting **first-dataframe** wrapped to build displayed as **second dataframe** ? `EXACTLY OPPOSITE TO EXPLODE OPTION`

Comment: can you give example of what you are trying to do? what have you done thus far? and expected output?

Comment: please note that with out proper example just explaining in words wont help answerers as well as you also. Hope you got it it should be reproducable example to give solid answer. next time take care

Comment: Please provide some input/output data as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples

Comment: please let me know if question is still unclear.